# Does one nginx worker process handle two requests concurrently or one by one?

Tags: c, nginx, pipeline, epoll, aio

> The really cool part about the filter
>   chain is that each filter doesn't wait
>   for the previous filter to finish; it
>   can process the previous filter's
>   output as it's being produced, sort of
>   like the Unix pipeline. (from [here](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html))

I guess the above is talking about such code **at the end** of each filter:

```
if (!chain_contains_last_buffer)
    return ngx_http_next_body_filter(r, in);
```

That is,nginx chains the filters one by one.
But as it's **at the end** of each filter,it has to wait until current filter is done. I don't see how nginx manages to make `each filter doesn't wait for the previous filter to finish`.

So the above is about the concurrency of nginx filter,next is about the concurrency of nginx request handling:

As we know nginx uses `epoll` to deal with requests:

```
events = epoll_wait(ep, event_list, (int) nevents, timer);
for (i = 0; i < events; i++) {
   ...
   rev->handler(rev);
}
```

With code like above,I don't think nginx can handle two request concurrently,it can only do it one by one(each `handler` finishes its job fast enough so the next request gets handled pretty soon),right?

Or is there any gotcha I'm missing?

Comment: You are right. Nginx can't serve two or more requests concurrently in one worker.

Comment: @CyberDem0n,what about the filter pipelining thing? Theoretically,I don't think it's possible in a single process without threading.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to test this. Write a filter that sleeps, and use it in the filter chain. Then test to see if you can get nginx to serve a request while a previous request is sleeping.

Then run the test again, but this time don't let the filter sleep, make it wait using select timeouts like so:

```
/* wait 1.5 secs */
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 1;
tv.tv_usec = 500000;
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```